# Jquery Stop Load and Clear Interval

Tags: php, jquery, clearinterval

I'm using jquery to load an external page and display it in a DIV called View.

I have 2 buttons Go & Stop.

This is working, but when I click stop it can take a few seconds.
Any way to make it stop straight away ?

```
$("#Go").click(function () { 
    $("#view").load("test.php");
    refreshId = setInterval(function() { 
    $("#view").load("test.php"); }, 1000);  
});


$("#Stop").click(function () { 
    clearInterval(refreshId); $("#view").stop(); 
    $.ajax({ url : 'new.php' });
} });
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",
    success: function(msg){
      $("#view").html(msg);
    }
});
```

and stop call:

```
//kill the request
xhr.abort()
```

Comment: The stop submits data to a different page.